# Are there any reverse novels in Esperanto?

Tags: literature

A reverse novel is one which the story is told in reverse chronological order, such as by presenting the chapters to be read in reverse order. It might seem that a crime novel told in such a way would be anti-climatic, or boring, but there is a highly-successful instance of such in English, namely, “[The October List](http://enciklopedia-vortaro-de-la-merk-angla.weebly.com/temo-the-october-list.html)”, by Jeffery Deaver. So, are there any reverse novels in Esperanto?

Comment: http://lernu.net/eo/forumo/temo/23086

Answer (score 4):

I will go out on a limb and say: No, I don't think so.

Comment: I got a good laugh from your "going out on a limb" but I'm going to wait and see if anybody can respond more definitively or with more detail before I vote. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Probably not, but there probably are "Stream of Consciousness" plays a la James Joyce...